# xcodebuild can't build when no physical iOS

Tags: xcodebuild

**xcodebuild manual:**

Some actions (such as building) may be performed without an actual device present.  To build against a
     platform generically instead of a specific device, the destination specifier may be prefixed with the
     optional string **"generic/"**, indicating that the platform should be targeted generically.  An example of
     a generic destination is the **"iOS Device"** destination displayed in Xcode's UI when no physical iOS
     device is present.

**try it:**

> xcodebuild -scheme Test -destination "platform=iOS,name=generic/iOS" 
>    xcodebuild: error: Was unable to find a destination matching the arguments to the -destination flag:
>       The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

Comment: I've never used `-destination` as `-configuration` and `-target` or `-scheme` work just fine.

Comment: I've also never used `-destination` switch and everything was always working fine.

Answer (score 26):

According to the *examples* on the [xcodebuild man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html), the correct way to specify a generic iOS destination is:

```
xcodebuild -destination generic/platform=iOS ...
```

(The wording of the description for this is definitely ambiguous or misleading. I wouldn't have figured this out without the example.)

Comment: `xcodebuild -workspace some.xcworkspace -scheme "Some App" -sdk iphoneos -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath build/SomeApp archive` xcodebuild just sleeps ((

Answer (score 3):

If you get the following error:

```
*xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project WatsonCore with scheme WatsonCoreTests.
    Reason: A build only device cannot be used to run this target.*
```

Try this: it works for me in terms of generic OS. Hardware device still needs to be specified.

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme YourScheme -project YourProject -configuration Debug **-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'** clean build test CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the -desintation "platform=generic/..." flag to work either, but specifying the -sdk flag using an iPhone OS SDK rather than a simulator SDK (`xcodebuild -showsdks` shows the available SDKs) allowed me to build successfully without a device connected:

```
xcodebuild -project someproject.xcodeproj -scheme somescheme -sdk iphoneos8.0 -configuration Debug
```

Answer (score -1):

It works when you prefix destination-specifier with 'generic/'.

```
ios.xcode.destination.device=generic/platform=iOS
```

Worked for me!!